# JavaScript contact form validation

Tags: javascript

I want to find out if a phone number contains +46, 0046 or 070.
I could only do for the +46 and used a comma to write 0046, but this code didn't work.

```
if (tel.indexOf("+46") == -1) {
  text= "Måste ha +46";
  error_message.innerHTML = text; 
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: Use 'or' operator like this: `if(tel.indexOf('+46')==-1 || tel.indexOf('0046')==-1) { // ...`

Comment: Hey! It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```
const re = /^(0046|\+46|070)/;
if (!re.test(tel)) {
  text= "Mobilnumret måste börja med 0046, +46 eller 070";
  error_message.innerHTML = text; 
  return false; 
}
```

Tests:

```js
const re = /^(0046|\+46|070)/;

let tel = "0046...."
console.log(re.test(tel))
tel = "+46...."
console.log(re.test(tel))
tel = "070...."
console.log(re.test(tel))
tel = "46...."
console.log(re.test(tel))
```